# Python запустить сторонний file.py с долгими циклами при обращении к моему сайту на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, консоль, flask, pythonanywhere

С питоном знаком не очень

Понадобилось для [этого](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) сервиса

У них можно запустить в консоли какой-нибудь размещенный там скрипт

Мне нужно при определенном запросе к моему сайту запустить скрипт в консоли программно

Так как в нем есть долгие циклы, то с помощью `import` делать не вариант, так как запрос должен достаточно быстро что-то вернуть

Пробовал так же с помощью `os` и `subprocess` - не помогло

Что можно сделать?

Comment: чтобы вернуть запрос, не дожидаясь окончания выполнения циклов, можно асинхронную очередь задач использовать типа celery.

Comment: @jfs пока без примера не очень понятно

Comment: чтобы примеры найти, flask celery в гугл вбейте. Не знаю, работает ли это в контексте pythonanywhere.

Comment: @jfs Вроде разобрался, но мне нужно, чтоб скрипт был запущен в консоли. Чтоб я например открыл вкладку Consoles и увидел бы там этот исполняющийся скрипт

Comment: @jfs на pythonanywhere не поддерживается Celery

Answer (score 0):

Ответом является - асинхронное программирование.

Т.к. на данном хостинге ограничены потоки, то решение только одно.

Поддерживаю [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) в том, что нужно просмотреть документацию к [celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/)

Также можно посмотреть "полуродные" библиотеки [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)(для асинхронных запросов)

Comment: Вроде разобрался, но мне нужно, чтоб скрипт был запущен в консоли. Чтоб я например открыл вкладку Consoles и увидел бы там этот исполняющийся скрипт

Comment: Celery на этом PythonAnywhere к тому же не поддерживается

Comment: Тогда используйте самописные скрипты по запуску деменов.
К сожалению у pythonanywhere ограничение работы скрипта - 6 часов(примерно), а следовательно через 6 часов любой скрипт закроется принудительно.